# A function equal to its Taylor series on an interval is also equal to its Taylor series on a subinterval with different center

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Suppse the power series $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-a )^n$ has positive radius of convergence $R$ and thus defines a real analytic fuction $f$ on $(a-R,a+R).$If $x_0$ is a point with $|x_0-a|<R,$ Let $r=R-|x_0-a|,$then we can certainly define a power series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^n(x_0 )}{n!}(x-x_0)^n,x\in(x_0-r,x_0+r).$$
Prove: $$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^n(x_0 )}{n!}(x-x_0)^n , x\in(x_0-r, x_0+r).$$

---

The following is my way of thinking:

Using **Taylor's Theorem**,Let $x$ is a fixed point in $(x_0-r, x_0+r),$then for every $n\in\mathbb{N^{+}},$we have
$$f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^k(x_0 )}{k!}(x-x_0)^k=\frac{f^{n+1}({\xi }_{n})}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1},$$

where ${\xi }_{n}$ is a ponit between $x_0$ and $x$ .$$\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^k(x_0 )}{k!}(x-x_0)^k \right|\leq \frac{|f^{n+1}({\xi }_{n})|}{(n+1)!}|x-x_0|^{n+1}\leq |f^{n+1}({\xi }_{n})|\frac{r^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},$$

Since that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{r^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=0,$

***If we have a positive constant $M$, such that $|f^{n+1}({\xi }_{n})|\leq M,(n=1,2,...).$We can get the answer!***

---

Until now I have failed to find this $M$,I have a hunch on that $M$ should be exist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you find the theorem ?

Comment: @Tony Piccolo：http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897179/f-in-c-omega-a-r-ar-mathbbr

Comment: @900 sit-ups a day@Jack D'Aurizio@RecklessReckoner@paul garrett @hardmath@Jonas Meyer：If you have any idea,please give some hints.

Comment: See Krantz/Parks _A Primer of Real Analytic Functions_ (1992), proposition 1.2.2 (1.2.3 in the 2nd ed. 2002), p. 12.